# ftp...Return to your local Kermit and give a RECEIVE command

Tags: kermit

I'm testing ftp/kermit (trying command line to see why it's not working with script), and for some reason I get "Return to your local Kermit and give a RECEIVE command", but there wasn't a spot to enter it at that statment...there were weird characters on the screen at that point.  I'm not sure what this refers to and haven't found much useful info with a search online. This is what I'm seeing.  I'm not exactly sure about the feedback from kermit.

```
$/apps/bin/kermit
C-Kermit>ftp open MMMM /USER:user\useruser /PASSWORD: pwpw   #changed for safety
Connected to MMMM.
User logged in.
Switching LOCUS  for file-management commands to REMOTE.
Remote system type is Windows_NT.
Default transfer mode is TEXT ("ASCII")
(/home/mcleary/k_test/michele/) C-Kermit>cd /home/mcleary/k_test/michele/
Switching LOCUS for file-management commands to LOCAL.
Service not available, connection closed by server
(/home/mcleary/k_test/michele/) C-Kermit>ascii
(/home/mcleary/k_test/michele/) C-Kermit>put test.txt ../20210916_test.txt
Return to your local Kermit and give a RECEIVE command.

KERMIT READY TO SEND...
 SENT: (0 files)

*************************
SEND-class command failed.
 Packets sent: 2
 Retransmissions: 11
 Timeouts: 12
 Damaged packets: 0
 Fatal Kermit Protocol Error: Too many retries

HINTS... If the preceding error message does not explain the failure:
 . Adjust the timeout method (see HELP SET SEND).
 . Increase the retry limit (see HELP SET RETRY).
 . Try it again with SET STREAMING OFF.
 . Try it again with SET PARITY SPACE.
 . As a last resort, give a ROBUST command and try again.
Also:
 . Be sure the source file has read permission.
 . Be sure the target directory has write permission.
(Use SET HINTS OFF to suppress hints.)
*************************
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you returned to your local Kermit, so you won't have been able to enter the receive command. Having said that, is Kermit really still a thing? I thought it had vanished, along with dinosaurs

Comment: We are in the process of switching to lftp, but I'm trying to make sure I have kermit working in my dev environment before I test the new thing. I've had to get through a lot of environement setup things, etc, to get ready to test, plus I haven't ftp'd in 20+ years so I'm really not that clear on the whole thing and am trying to understand it.  We do have kermit working/used in prod env.

Comment: Fair enough! The key sequence to return to local mode is apparently Ctrl `/` and then `c` (at least that's what https://glasstty.com/?p=662 tells me)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 things

```
(/home/mcleary/k_test/michele/) C-Kermit>cd /home/mcleary/k_test/michele/
Switching LOCUS for file-management commands to LOCAL.
Service not available, connection closed by server
```

remote system is windows NT, are you sure you want to `cd` and not `lcd` ? Path like `/home/..` make me think you want to localy change dir (`lcd` in kermit/ftp) not `cd`.

kermit used to work in two ways, either

```
put/receive on remote kermit session
disconnect from remote
receive/put on local kermit session
wait for transfert
reconnect (`recon`) to remote
```

or

```
tell remote to go server (on unix this was `kermit -s` )
disconnect
put/receive from local kermit session
```

you have to find out disconnection key (most likely <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>/</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> as roaima's pointed out), what does `man kermit` says ?

Comment: lcd worked while cd wasn't working.  Thanks.

Comment: Accepted for lcd part.  Good point about put and receive parts.

Comment: my last actual usage of  `kermit`  was about 30 years ago, at those times `goto` and dinosaures roams the world ...

Comment: All the tech in this office is that old

Answer (score 0):

This wound up moving the file:

```
$/apps/bin/kermit
C-Kermit>ftp open MMMM /USER:user\useruser /PASSWORD: pwpw   #changed for safety
Connected to MMMM.
User logged in.
Default transfer mode is TEXT ("ASCII")
(/home/mcleary/k_test/michele/) C-Kermit>lcd /home/mcleary/k_test/michele/
(/home/mcleary/k_test/michele/) C-Kermit>ascii

(/home/mcleary/k_test/michele/) C-Kermit>pwd

(/home/mcleary/k_test/michele/) C-Kermit>cd destdir

(/home/mcleary/k_test/michele/) C-Kermit>put test.txt 20210916_test.txt
(/home/mcleary/k_test/michele/) C-Kermit>ls
```

And I see the file in the dest dir.

I was doing 2 things wrong.  I was giving `..` in renaming the `test.txt` file and didn't have permission there.  I also needed to `cd` to  the destination dir as well as `lcd` to source dir.  That moved the file.

Thanks everyone! I feel like I'm getting a handle on converting this to `lftp` now.